# having two type of content_type in case you have set one for all

Tags: javascript, api, axios, http-headers

it would be great if someone can help me with this issue.
i have set the header of all apis to `"Content-Type": "application/json"`
like the code below we have this code in a file that is imported in all api js files:

```
const httpClient = axios.create({
headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  }
})
```

but now we need to have a different `Content-Type` for sending images with JSON content  like `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data"`
how can i define a new different header that renders every time we declare it
and how can i do this by code?

**each api file that gets the `Content-Type` by default:**

```
export const create = (data) => {
return httpClient({
    url: '/api/create',
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
        "X-CSRF-TOKEN"
    },

    data: data
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't understand your question clearly but i think that you want something like that

```
export const create = (data) => {
    return httpClient({
        url: '/api/create',
        method: 'post',
        headers: data.headers ?
            {
                "X-CSRF-TOKEN":".......",
                ...data.headers
            } 
            : 
            {
                "X-CSRF-TOKEN":".......",
            },
        data: data.body
    })
}
```

In this solution if `data.headers`not null, it will be appended to already declared headers. if `data.headers` is null, it will only send already have been declared headers.